# postgresql(aws redshift) error 1204 String length exceeds DDL length

Tags: python, postgresql, import, amazon-redshift

I am trying to import csv into aws redshift( postgresql 8.x) .

The data flow is:
mysql ->  parquet files on s3 -> csv files  on s3 -> redshift.

### Table structure

The mysql table sql:

```
create table orderitems
(
  id                         char(36) collate utf8_bin not null
    primary key,
  store_id                   char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
  ref_type                   int                       not null,
  ref_id                     char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
  store_product_id           char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
  product_id                 char(36) collate utf8_bin not null,
  product_name               varchar(50)               null,
  main_image                 varchar(200)              null,
  price                      int                       not null,
  count                      int                       not null,
  logistics_type             int                       not null,
  time_create                bigint                    not null,
  time_update                bigint                    not null,
  ...
);
```

I used same sql to create table in redshift , but it got error while importing csv.

### My code import csv to redshift (python)

```
# parquet is dumpy by sqoop
p2 = 'xxx'
df = pd.read_parquet(path)    

with smart_open.smart_open(p2, 'w') as f:
    df.to_csv(f, index=False)  # python3 default encoding is utf-8

conn = psycopg2.connect(CONN_STRING)

sql="""COPY %s FROM '%s' credentials 'aws_iam_role=%s' region 'cn-north-1' 
delimiter ',' FORMAT AS CSV IGNOREHEADER 1 ; commit ;""" %  (to_table, p2, AWS_IAM_ROLE)
print(sql)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql)
conn.close()
```

### Got error

By checking `STL_LOAD_ERRORS` found error on `product_name` column
[image]

- row_field_value : .............................................215g/...
- err_code: 1204
- err_reason: String length exceeds DDL length

The real_value is `伊利畅轻蔓越莓奇亚籽风味发酵乳215g/瓶`( chinese) .

So it looks like some encoding problem. Since mysql is utf-8 and the csv is utf-8 too , I don't know what is wrong .

Comment: I'm assuming that reference to "mysql" in the last line is a typo.

Comment: @Nathan Griffiths No,  the data is original from mysql with utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your column is a varchar data type, with length 50. That's 50 *bytes*, not 50 *characters*. The string example you've given looks to be about 16 chinese characters, which are probably 3 bytes each (UTF-8) and four ASCII characters (one byte each), so about 52 bytes. That's longer than the byte length of the column, so the import fails.

Comment: But aws docs says   `VARCHAR` : `4 bytes + total bytes for characters, where each character can be 1 to 4  
 .bytes ` .https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Character_types.html

Comment: `varchar(50)` is also safe in mysql .

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment - yes, VARCHAR requires 4 bytes of storage, plus however many bytes are allocated for the actual characters. In this case you have allocated 50 bytes for characters but the actual length of the string you're importing is longer than 50 bytes, so it can't be imported without truncating the string. Therefore the COPY statement generates an error.

Comment: I had a quick scan of the MySQL documentation and the definition of VARCHAR(50) is not equivalent between MySQL and Redshift. In MySQL the 50 represents the maximum number of _characters_ and the number of bytes per character depends on the collation being used. In Redshift the 50 represents a fixed number of _bytes_ , regardless of the number of characters used. So you shouldn't assume that a string that could be stored in a MySQL VARCHAR(50) column can be stored in a Redshift VARCHAR(50) column, as the MySQL data could be longer than 50 bytes.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. The aws document make me think `VARCHAR(50)` stand for `50 of  4 bytes characters` . Because same schema is safe in mysql, I  think mention that may help people who like you knows the different between mysql and postgresql , to catch the problem more easily  :) .